# Assignment in Ruby does not work as expected

Tags: ruby

i have this statement:

```
if user = params[:user] && action == :delete
end
```

why is user always set to :delete?

should not it be set to user name if user passed or nil otherwise.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your explanation. It does not make much sense now.

Comment: Do you mean user == params[:user]? I'm not sure what the question is asking but user = params[:user] doesn't make sense for an if statement.

Comment: @James, Its not set to `:delete` its checking simultaneous presence of two conditions `:user` and also `action` is `:delete`

Comment: doh, it is so obvious :) (user = params[:user]) && ... thanks uDaY, you pointed me to right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `()` around the assignment in Ruby for it to be evaluated as you expect

```
if (user = params[:user]) && action == :delete
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` binds stronger than the assingment. You can use `and` instead if you're keen on omitting the parentheses:

```
if user = params[:user] and action == :delete
end
```

As a matter of [style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) - using the return value of = (an assignment) is ok, but surround the assignment with parentheses.

```
  # good - shows intended use of assignment
  if (v = array.grep(/foo/)) ...

  # bad
  if v = array.grep(/foo/) ...

  # also good - shows intended use of assignment and has correct precedence.
  if (v = self.next_value) == 'hello' ...
```

The use of `and` and `or` in conditional expressions is discouraged so you're better off with the solution suggested by Ian Bishop.